# Android line divider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-kotlin, data-class

Learning android with a two friends and right now we're focusing on just UI portion. One friend gave us the task of creating a display with dashed line divider. We're trying to add it in the Adapter file so it can be loaded in our fragment as part of the recycler view but can't figure out how.

Here's the layout in where the dotted line drawable gets passed in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashes"
        android:background="@drawable/dashes_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a way you can set line divider for RecyclerView

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, VERTICAL).apply {
           setDrawable(getDrawable(context, R.drawable.separator))
    })
```

You can change the drawable as you see fit.

**Update**: add drawable separator.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
  <size android:height="3dp"/>
  <stroke
      android:color="#000000"
      android:dashWidth="10px"
      android:dashGap="10px"
      android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: where do I add this

Comment: You can use it on your RecyclerView, the view where you inflate your RecyclerView

Comment: You can do it on your activity or fragment whose layout has a recyclerview

Comment: @PizzaParty123 Can you elaborate more? Did you just want to add some dashed lines as items of the RecyclerView, or you havve already had a list of items inside the RecyclerView and want to add line divider to them?

Answer (score 0):

you can try replaceing Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:background="@drawable/dashes_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:text="test"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashes"
        android:background="@drawable/dashes_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```